# Ubuntu cannot recognize USB disk devices

Tags: 18.04, usb

I have a desktop PC and a laptop PC, both running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
In the desktop PC there are 8 USB ports. I know that they all work, because when I connect the keyboard or mouse the system recognizes them.

However, I can't read USB disk devices. When I insert a USB disk in the laptop, the system recognizes it, but in the desktop PC nothing happens.

I have tried with different USB disks, old and modern. Same behavior: they are recognized in the laptop PC, but nothing happens in the desktop PC.

This problem has been showing up for some time. In the past everything worked fine.

Another thing, I don't know if it is related, but I noticed that when I open the Ubuntu file manager, there are two new items: `efi` and `Filesystem root` (see screenshot below):

[image: Ubuntu file manager]

In the past they were not present in the file manager.

Solutions?

Comment: It would make it easier to help, if you tell us more about your two computers and the Ubuntu systems in them. One way of doing it is to [download and run the `system-info` script (of the Ubuntu Forums)](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/). Please do it when USB drives are connected. and let the script upload result files to a pastebin for each of the computers. Finally, edit your original question to post links to the two pastebins.

Comment: This is really 2 questions: for the USB question, run `journalctl -n 50` right after inserting the flash drive.  For the extra drives question, run `cat /etc/fstab`.  You can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1386313/edit) your question with the results of both commands.